# Windows reports "Out of Memory" despite huge pagefile

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, virtual-memory, pagefile

How to force Windows to use the swap file to the fullest?

I use Windows 7 64-bit and I have 16 GB of RAM + 8 GB (static) pagefile.

When I open many Chrome tabs, and the physical memory is almost full (according to Task Manager which shows only RAM), I start getting "Out of Memory" errors.

When this happens I have to bookmark some of the Chrome tabs to read them later, which is time-consuming and simply annoying.

What needs to be done to increase the size of available memory with the help of pagefile? I know that pagefile is slower, but I don't care.

Comment: Out of memory means (almost) all virtual memory has been consumed. Including the page file. The message is unrelated to physical memory usage.

Comment: @DanielB if my pagefile has been fully consumed, why does `wmic pagefile list /format` say `AllocatedBaseSize=8192` `CurrentUsage=2443` `PeakUsage=6509` ?

Comment: I already commented on that below. To view the actually relevant number, in Task Manager, go to “Performance” and check “Commit” in the “System” group.

Comment: Ok ty.. Will increasing pagefile size to 64 GB help or do I need to buy more RAM? @DanielB

Comment: How many tabs are you talking about having open and how many extensions do you have enabled?  I've never seen Chromium browsers exceed 2.5GB of RAM with ~20 extensions and 25+ tabs open.  Chrome is a memory hog, and if you're running with only 2GB  - 3GB of RAM available, you'll experience issues when running Chrome.  There's some other issue at play here, as either there's likely a program(s) that are depleting available RAM, possibly using RAM heavy extensions, too many enabled extensions, or an insanely large amount of open browser tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses a lot of memory for its many tabs.

Go to Control Panel, System, Advance System Settings, System Protection, Advanced, Advanced and set your page file size to be automatic. Then it will increase as needed

Comment: I know how to modify pagefile size, but thank you for the answer.

Why does Windows report "Out of Memory" when pagefile is not even 30% full?

C:\Users\User>wmic pagefile list /format

AllocatedBaseSize=8192
CurrentUsage=2443
Description=C:\pagefile.sys
InstallDate=20160518033709.309600+180
Name=C:\pagefile.sys
PeakUsage=6509
Status=
TempPageFile=FALSE

Comment: I think if you use Automatic, it should adjust real time and not give you that message. Try that

Comment: `Win32_PageFileUsage::CurrentUsage` does not indicate commit charge.

Comment: The commit charge has nothing to do with either RAM or pagefile usage. These values are irrelevant to out of memory errors.